# Is it possible to install Linux OS on a computer with SSH with no monitor?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I have an old computer I want to use as a Minecraft server. It has no working display ports and has Windows 10 installed on it.

The computer is an HP Pavilion m9047c and I want to install Ubuntu server on it.

I have a Windows computer, a USB drive, and I have a box full of miscellaneous cords.

Comment: Your best bet will probably not be SSH, but by preinstalling directly to the main drive, from another PC. But maybe reconsider. This PC is ancient and its CPU is incredibly slow by today's standards.

Comment: Do you know any software that can directly install the os onto the drive? I have an adapter for the boot drive for my pc.

Comment: Any software can be used to install Linux onto a hard drive. Just pull it out of the new machine, connect it to a system that you do have a display on (via USB adapter; for example) and you should be able to set up the drive as a destination disk.

Comment: Many distros allow you to create an iso which when booted from will install without any interaction from a user at all.

Comment: It's certainly possible, but if it really doesn't have a working display output you're just setting yourself up for a world of hurt when it just stops working for some reason. If there's a way to get a monitor working, just do that, and if there isn't, I wouldn't use that machine

Comment: If this site ( https://www.computer-specifications.com/specifications/HewlettPackard-PavilionElitem9047c-Specs.html )is to be believed, the cpu should be a  2.40GHz Intel Core 2 Quad Q6600. Sounds like it should be very useful still. Better than a Raspberri Pi (maybe several Pi's), and free

Answer (score 3):

SSH is not itself a bootloader or Operating System. SSH is depending on being installed in another operating system.

Certain computers have remote consoles which allow them to run a virtual display useful for base-level OS installs, but these are usually dedicated server machines. Even high end specialized end-user computers do not have a remote headless console option except in very specialized cases.

What I recommend is you connect a monitor for the install and setup, and once you've got Linux set up and confirmed that SSH works, you can disconnect the monitor and proceed with using the system as you want.